# How to call a WebAPI from Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, windows-services, asp.net-web-api

I have an application written in Windows Service and this app need to make a call to a WebAPI written in Asp.Net MVC 4 WebAPi. this method in WebAPI return a DTO with primitive type, something like:

```
class ImportResultDTO {
   public bool Success { get; set; }
   public string[] Messages { get; set; }
}
```

and in my webapi

```
public ImportResultDTO Get(int clientId) {
   // process.. and create the dto result.
   return dto;
}
```

My question is, how can I call the webApi from the Windows Service? I have my URL and value of parameter, but I don't know how to call and how to deserialize the xml result to the DTO.

Thank you

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: In addition to referencing the HttpClient as people recommend, it will make life easier if you place the ImportResultDTO in its own class library (your service model library) and then reference that library from both the Web API service and the Windows service. You can then let the HttpClient handle the materialization of the service call data into the strongly typed DTO class.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx). You will obviously need to edit the fake base address and request URI in the example below but this also shows a basic way to check the response status as well.

```
// Create an HttpClient instance
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8888/");

// Usage
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/importresults/1").Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var dto = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ImportResultDTO>().Result;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
}
```

Comment: Thank you blins, is there any way to check if the URL of my WebAPI is availible before I call `client.GetAsync(...).Result` ? I mean it because the internet connection or my webapi could be unstable and I need to check it before to do a correct eventLog for it. Thank you.

Comment: Could you not just wrap the call to GetAysnc in a try/catch block and handle the possible Exception? Try it and follow the stack trace, the inner exceptions look like what you are after (e.g. "No connection could be made because...")

Answer (score 4):

You can install this NuGet package [Microsoft ASP.NET Web API Client Libraries](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/4.0.20710.0) to your Windows Service project.

Here is a simple code snippet demonstrating how to use HttpClient:

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = client.GetAsync(uriOfYourService).Result;
        var content = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ImportResultDTO>().Result;
```

(I'm calling .Result() here for the sake of simplicity...)

For more sample of HttpClient, please check this out:  [List of ASP.NET Web API and HttpClient Samples.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/26/asp-net-web-api-and-httpclient-samples.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Maggie. I vote up your awser. Is there any way to check if the URL of my WebAPI is availible before I call client.GetAsync(...).Result ? I mean it because the internet connection or my webapi could be unstable and I need to check it before to do a correct eventLog for it. Thank you.