# how to display 10 first rows from excel sheet with asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel, html

I need to display just 10 first rows from my excel sheet, i can only display all the excel data using "@Foreach".
please find the controller and the view below.
this is how i extract data from excel:

```
string path2 = "D:/Project/SesameIncident.xlsx";

        Excel.Application application2 = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook workbook2 = application2.Workbooks.Open(path2);
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet2 = workbook2.ActiveSheet;
        Excel.Range range2 = worksheet2.UsedRange;
        List<SesameIn> ListSesame = new List<SesameIn>();
        for (int row = 2; row <= range2.Rows.Count; row++)

        {
            SesameIn Se = new SesameIn();
            Se.AssignedGroup= (((Excel.Range)range2.Cells[row, 1]).Text);
            Se.Open = (((Excel.Range)range2.Cells[row, 2]).Text);
            Se.Assigned = (((Excel.Range)range2.Cells[row, 3]).Text);
            Se.PendingCustomer = (((Excel.Range)range2.Cells[row, 4]).Text);
            Se.ClosedComplete = (((Excel.Range)range2.Cells[row, 5]).Text);
            Se.Resolved = (((Excel.Range)range2.Cells[row, 6]).Text);
            Se.Total = (((Excel.Range)range2.Cells[row, 7]).Text);



            ListSesame.Add(Se);

        }

        ViewBag.ListSesames = ListSesame;
```

and this is the view code :

```
 <div class="item">
        <h1><img src="~/Web/PendingCustomer.png" /> Sesame Pending Tickets </h1>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Assigned To</th>
            <th>Opened</th>
            <th>Priortity</th>
            <th>Assigned Group</th>


            </thead>
            <tbody>
```

@foreach (var In in ViewBag.ListSesameIncidents) 
{

```
    <tr>
        @if (@In.Status == "Pending Customer")
        {

            <td>@In.Number</td>
            <td>@In.AssignedTo</td>
            <td>@In.Opened</td>
            <td>@In.Priority </td>
            <td>@In.Status</td>
            <td>@In.AssignedGroup</td>

        }



    </tr>



}



            </tbody>

        </table>
        <br />

        <div class="carousel-caption">


        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try this... `ViewBag.ListTsesames = ListTSesame.Take(5);`

Comment: as u see in the view i have to test if the status its "Pending Customer" or not, so in the excel sheet u will find rows with different status.

Comment: i tried with `ViewBag.ListTsesames = ListTSesame.Take(10);` it display the first 10 rows with the Status different to   "Pending Customer"

Comment: Then do this, `ViewBag.ListSesames = ListSesam.Where(x=>x.Status == "Pending Customer").Take(10);`

Comment: The [Office interop libraries are not supported from in IIS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757), it is highly reccomended you switch to the [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) to read excel files on a server.

Comment: i need to execute the code every one hour,  how can i do it @Hari Prasad ?

Comment: That's a following question, I suggest close this question and ask new question.

Comment: i thing that u have to vote the question to ask one more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest use `Linq` extension methods and filter the Data.

```
ViewBag.ListSesames = ListSesam
                        .Where(x=>x.Status == "Pending Customer")   // Look for pending customers
                        .Take(10);                                  // Take top 10
```

Comment: how can i close the question ?

Comment: Post new question with the new title saying I want to execute logic for every 5 minutes.

Comment: i tried to create another question but i can't  "It looks like you might need a break - take a breather and come back soon! "

Comment: Ohh looks like you don't have enough reputations to post one more question. You have to wait for 2 days it seems.

Comment: but u can help me if u want Haris da

Comment: Usually we don't need timer specific things in ASP.Net , if you are still interested check this [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33448849/4422347)

Comment: hello @Hari Parsad i post a new question as u asked. i need your help? Link is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261735/refresh-every-5-minutes-en-asp-net-mvc/38262022#38262022

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq .Take(10) to show the first 10 items.

Comment: as u see in the view i want only to select the rows where the status its "Pending Customer "