# refresh every 5 minutes en asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

The controller display the data from the excel sheet.
I need that the controller check the excel sheet every 1 hour, also the views should be updated.
This is my controller code:

```
string path3 = "D:/Project/Sesame Incident Dump_20160317.xls";

Excel.Application application3 = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbook3 = application3.Workbooks.Open(path3);
Excel.Worksheet worksheet3 = workbook3.ActiveSheet;
Excel.Range range3 = worksheet3.UsedRange;
List<SesameIncident> ListSesameIncident = new List<SesameIncident>();
for (int row = 2; row <= range3.Rows.Count; row++)
{
    SesameIncident S = new SesameIncident();
    S.Number = (((Excel.Range)range3.Cells[row, 1]).Text);
    S.AssignedTo = (((Excel.Range)range3.Cells[row, 5]).Text);
    S.Opened = (((Excel.Range)range3.Cells[row, 6]).Text);
    S.Status = (((Excel.Range)range3.Cells[row, 7]).Text);
    S.Priority = (((Excel.Range)range3.Cells[row, 10]).Text);
    S.AssignedGroup = (((Excel.Range)range3.Cells[row, 12]).Text);

    ListSesameIncident.Add(S);

}

ViewBag.ListSesameIncidents = ListSesameIncident
       .Where(x => x.Status == "Pending Customer").Take(13);
```

Comment: controller will have to go through your file every time the action call it, unless some kind of caching is used

Comment: or data could be stored in database, i dont get your full implementation idea

Comment: the controller have to go through the excel sheets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a `Header` to your `HttpContext.Response` in your controller

```
HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("refresh", "300; url=" + Url.Action("Index"));
```

Comment: what about the time that i need it ?  "300 !!!" or i have to use "1000" for one second

Comment: i added before the method that i want to executed every 1 hour or inside ?

Comment: It's 300 second, 5 minutes

Comment: the position doesn't matter. You just add this line to your controller and the View that it returns will refresh every 5 minutes, and when the View refresh the controller code will be executed again

Comment: Could I ask If How can I make this in Ajax way without this flicker ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function () { 
      location.reload();
    }, 5 * 60 * 1000);
</script>
```

refer [Refresh Page for interval using js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038183/refresh-page-for-interval-using-js)

You can refresh the page this way

for the controller you might need a table in database to refer, when was last updated, for reference you will have to store reference data permanently , this is my opinion, I never had such requirement

Comment: i can use the sleep ?

Answer (score 0):

To run something periodically without user interaction (that is, without a request to initiate it), a web application isn't what you want. Instead, you're looking for either a Windows Service or perhaps a simple Console Application scheduled to run at regular intervals by the host system's scheduling software (Windows Task Scheduler, cron, etc.). See [How to execute a method in Asp.net MVC for every 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536751/how-to-execute-a-method-in-asp-net-mvc-for-every-24-hours)

I would rather think about caching that could potentially save reading xls every time. See [How to cache data in a MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343899/how-to-cache-data-in-a-mvc-application)

Answer (score 0):

- To update the client every X second is quite simple. Just use a
  [meta
  http-equiv](http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp)
  With the value `refresh` in you page's Header.

  This solution is **clean** and **easy to read** and you will not be depending of a simple JavaScript loop.
- To update your excel sheet every X, you need another app with a
  Timer. You can do whatever you want, if you're using .net, a simple console application will do the work. If you are using Azure you could just use a worker role, that is exactly what a worker
  Is about ;p