# Communication between .netCore WebApi and Windows Service .net 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-web-api, windows-services

On one side i have a Asp.Net Core WebApi 1.1 project hosted on a web server providing REST endpoints. On the other side i have a Windows Service project using .net framework 2.0.
.net 2.0 is a requirement and i can't update to a later version.

> What is the best way to communicate between these two?

I never used .net2.0 so I'm not quite sure what my options are. Communicating with REST endpoints on the WebApi would be preferred, but i can't find a good way to achieve this as libraries like WCF/Json/.. are not available on 2.0.

Edit: The client (Windows Service) should be able to register itself to the web service (PUT), get a status and download a file from it (GET).

Comment: Did u try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942644/how-to-call-a-webapi-from-windows-service

Comment: System.Net.Http.HttpClient is not available for .net framework 2.0

Comment: What kind of communication you need? One way from service to web api (that is - just make web requests to the endpoint)?

Comment: I should be able to send requests (GET/POST/PUT) to the web api.  One way from service to web api should be enough.

Comment: Use a WebClient as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483182/calling-web-api-service-from-a-net-2-0-client

Comment: I ended up using WebClient as @Praveen suggested. Thank you!